# How show points of each question when producing exams' solution?

Tags: r, r-exams

When producing an exams' solution using `exams2pdf(... template="solution",...)` I define I `showpoints=T`, however, no points are shown for each of the questions. I get:

[image]

instead of:

[image]

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of the question above. The answer is not really satisfactory, though, it's just a couple of workarounds. I know how I can extend this in exams2pdf (and exams2html) but I haven't found the time, yet, to do so.

Comment: Well, I have to edit all the rmds... :)

Comment: Yes, not ideal, I know.